# What do foreachBatches contain in a streaming query from multiple Kafka topics?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Given a `DataStreamReader` configured to subscribe to multiple topics like this (see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)):

```scala
// Subscribe to multiple topics
spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1,topic2,topic3")
```

When I use `foreachBatch` on top of this, what will the batches contain?

- Each batch will only contain messages from one topic?
- Or can a batch contain messages coming from different topics?

In my use case, I'd like to have batches with messages coming from one topic only. Is it possible to configure this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the official documentation in [Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide (Kafka broker version 0.10.0 or higher)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html):

> // Subscribe to multiple topics
>
> ```
> ...
> .option("subscribe", "topic1,topic2")
> ```

The code above is what the underlying Kafka consumer (of the streaming query) subscribes to.

> When I use foreachBatch on top of this, what will the batches contain?
>
> - Each batch will only contain messages from one topic?

That's the proper answer.

> I'd like to have batches with messages coming from one topic only. Is it possible to configure this?

That's also documented in [Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide (Kafka broker version 0.10.0 or higher)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html):

> Each row in the source has the following schema:
>
> ...
>
> topic

In other words, the input Dataset will have `topic` column with the name of the topic a given row (record) comes from.

In order to have *"batches with messages coming from one topic only"* you simply `filter` or `where` with the one topic, e.g.

```
val messages: DataFrame = ...
assert(messages.isStreaming)

messages
  .writeStream
  .foreachBatch { case (df, batchId) =>
    val topic1Only = df.where($"topic" === "topic1")
    val topic2Only = df.where($"topic" === "topic2")
    ...
  }
```

Comment: As for the 2nd part of my question: By configuration I meant to avoid filtering, because batches need to be processed completely or not at all. However, when batches contain only messages from one topic, all is fine. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: @jacek Is there a way to programmatically write it instead of specifying a val for each topic? i was thinking of looping over a list of topics it seems inefficient

Comment: @collarblind Just use `topic` field and this row gets "routed" to this topic.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski my question is confusing. if i have topics `val topics=Seq("t1","t2")` and my `foreachBatch` has this,
`topics.map(t => df.where($"topic" === "t1").write()`. is it the same as your code?

Comment: Why are you `foreachBatch` while writing to Kafka since you've got the built-in data source?

Comment: i want to read from multiple topics and write each topic to their s3 location

Answer (score 1):

The batch will contain messages coming from all the topics (I'd say partitions, instead) that your consumer is subscribed to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it based on observation or is it documented somewhere? The question is about multiple _topics_ (and not about _partitions_).

Comment: @Beryllium Behind the scenes, the consumer subscribes to particular partitions of the given topic(s). If there is only one consumer in a consumer group then it subscribes to all of the partitions.